# Spread only overlapping elements of an object into a new one with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, lint

When you spread an object in TypeScript into another object all elements are spread. Also the elements which are not in the target type (new object after spread).

```
type ObjectA = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

type ObjectB = ObjectA & {
    c: string;
}

const instanceObjectB: ObjectB = {
    a: 'A',
    b: 'B',
    c: 'C'
}

const spreadObjectA: ObjectA = {...instanceObjectB};
console.log(spreadObjectA);
```

This is expected behavior for me, but I also see some problems with it. The `spreadObjectA` contains more data as it should and if I serialize and send it over to an API also the unnecessary data is included. So I usually "handcraft" the new objects:

```
const overlapObjectA: ObjectA = {a: instanceObjectB.a, b: instanceObjectB.b};
console.log(overlapObjectA);
```

I tried to do some research, but it was difficult to find anything. **So my questions are:**

1. Is there a flag in the TypeScript compiler or an option in ESLint, which helps me to prevent me from living in danger?
2. Can I configure Babel, so only the overlapping elements are spread? So the spread becomes type aware?
3. How you would deal with this in a big project with many developers?

**Here the code in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AQSgXigbwFBSFQCGAXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmA3AUXOVXU6wL555QkWIhTAAQlhFJUGAGS42hZJxoMWefnmQB7elSgMqxesgjwZE8hbGTs%20IiXIByNM4A0SqByjPxHrxVfAGFnTQFdfWBKMGoIYgATG1lrUVkpHAA6bKNgEzNkiV5WSIodABsITPKdRgAKClj4pLT0AEpWbT0DHQA3CGpy4jBCtFTLDHsyQyj881bxTOJ3b3JcucLFuGKu-Qqqmvq%20gaGR1rQOgSA).**

### Updated question

4. What would be an easy way to remove the excess properties?

Comment: There is a proposal for [exact types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936), but nothing to deal with this built-in in Typescript as far as I know